# Change x-axis scale size in a bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

For some set of data, here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
year = []
relative_recurrence = []
f = open('relative recurrence plot.txt', 'r')
for row in f:
    row = row.split(' ')
    year.append(row[0])
    relative_recurrence.append(float(row[1]))
plt.bar(year, relative_recurrence, color = 'g', label = 'HILDCAAS')
```

which generates a bar graph like this:

[image]

The values on the x-axis ranges from 1975 to 2017. And the values on the y-axis are some decimal values. In the x-axis of the plot, the values are overlapping. I want to change the scale as 1975, 1980, 1985 so on to keep them distinct and visible.

What is the required command?

I tried the xlim() command. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
year = []
relative_recurrence = []
f = open('relative recurrence plot.txt','r')
for row in f:
    row = row.split(' ')
    year.append(float(row[0]))
    relative_recurrence.append(float(row[1]))
plt.bar(year, relative_recurrence,color = 'g', label = 'HILDCAAS')
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(year), max(year) + 1, 5.0))
```

Comment: @AyushiNema Does it help?

Comment: I added the said command ```plt.xticks(np.arange(min(year), max(year) + 1, 1))
``` and got the error as : can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @AyushiNema Edited my answer with the full code, should work now

Comment: @AyushiNema On which line?

Comment: @AyushiNema Show me the full trace back

Comment: In the same line. My data is in integer format. Could you suggest something else. I have tried this earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236582/discussion-between-ayushi-nema-and-u12-forward).

Comment: @AyushiNema How about now?

Answer (score 0):

**Changing x-axis scale by own**

```
plt.xticks([item for item in range (enter desired range number)])
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"by own"* (seems incomprehensible)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68993244/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

**Examples:
Make changes as desired :)**

ax.set_xticks([item for item in range(0,len(x_draws),5)])

or

plt.set_xticks([item for item in range(0,len(x_draws),5)])